# Html Display apex chart in ContentFlow

Tags: html, apexcharts, contentflow

I am using [ContentFlow](http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php) library to display objects as cover flow view. When I am displaying images , it is working fine . But on using [apex charts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm) its view is getting disturbed. Is there any way to display apex charts in proper format using [ContentFlow](http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php) library?

Please provide some solid solution. I tried many things but they did not work